# Exponentiate a decimal number in Android SDK

Tags: java, android, math

I want to exponentiate a decimal number by 2 in the Android SDK. Currently, I can just do it with whole numbers, for this I use the following:

```
    a = Integer.parseInt(etA.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(etB.getText().toString());

    res = a*a + b*b;
    res = (int) Math.pow(res, 0.5);

    tvSol.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

As you can see, the user sets an input to `etA` and one to `etB`. The final solution is shown on the `tvSol`. I need to do this with decimal numbers rather than just whole numbers.

Comment: *"with decimal numbers"* You mean with `double` instead of `int`? If so, what's stopping you from using `double`?

Comment: *FYI:* It is better to use `Math.sqrt(res)` than `Math.pow(res, 0.5)`.

Comment: Maybe `Double.parseDouble` is the function you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will let you accept both whole numbers and decimal numbers.

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(etA.getText().toString());
double b = Double.parseDouble(etB.getText().toString());
double res = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);

tvSol.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

If you really want to use `Math.pow` you could do the following instead:

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(etA.getText().toString());
double b = Double.parseDouble(etB.getText().toString());
double res = Math.pow(Math.pow(a, 2.0) + Math.pow(b, 2.0), 0.5);

tvSol.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

This second approach will likely perform slower than the first and is harder to read.